# What does Microsoft suggest to make a WPF application persistent?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, linq, nhibernate, persistence

I am new to WPF. What i learned is that WPF follows the MVC pattern. My idea was designing a new application with WPF and NHibernate but NHibernate uses the MVVM pattern. This doesn't really fit together with the MVC from WPF. Ok, there are quit a lot "solutions" to handle this conflict, but for me this does not really sound good.

My question: Is there any "master way" to make data of a WPF desktop application persistent in a SQL-Server database? What does Microsoft say? What does you say?

Comment: I think you should read little more about design patterns such as MVC and MVVM.

Comment: If I understand the question, you want to persist application scoped settings on a database rather than a local file.  In this case you would derive a class from SettingsProvider and decorate it accordingly; and then create an instance of your class to access/save the information you wanted to persist between sucessive executions of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern Microsoft recommends in WPF is with the MVVM pattern. You can check this out in many blog articles but here is a good starting point:

[MSDN Magazine - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

If you want to learn more about Microsoft recommended architectures you can check out the patterns and practices website, or look at David Hayden's website which has a lot of great screen casts.

In terms of building a data access layer for a desktop client there are many approaches. Some common ones are Repository Pattern, Active Record, and using the ORM directly. Unlike NHibernate and Entity Framework, Active Record pattern isn't based on POCO. The objects hold persistence within themselves. This makes some distributed and disconnected scenarios more work. There is a trend away from repository pattern which is summarized in this article by Ayende:

[Ayende - Repository is the new Singleton](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

Basically according to this article your session object in NHibernate or DBContext object in Entity framework follow a kind of repository pattern in of themselves, so adding a repository layer is redundant.

In terms of MVVM, these patterns and technolgies will live in the Model. The View Model will act as an intermediary - so you will not, and should not, bind the view directly to your persistent objects.

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Nothing. YOu get it wrong - this is like asking what os Mercedes suggest as cleaning material for a car using a specific type of WINDSHIELD WIPER.

Basically persistence is one part of the application, WPF is presentation and another one. It makes ZERO difference how you present the data. You create a wag the dog situation.

> This doesn't really fit together with the MVC from WPF

As somene who has used this - it absolutely does. Totally.

> Ok, there are quit a lot "solutions" to handle this conflict, but for me this does not really 
>   sound good.

Learn more about adrchitecture.

> Is there any "master way" to make data of a WPF desktop application persistent in a SQL-Server 
>   database?

No. The same as with any other type of application - there always are tradeoffs, so a silver bullet does not exist. Thus - well - you have to come up with solutions, which takes experience.

> NHibernate but NHibernate uses the MVVM pattern

Last time I checked, NHibernate was an O/R mapper that was fully capable of supporting multiple different ways of handling applications. So, this statement is wrong.